# How can I speed up my Android App testing

Tags: android, testing, workflow

If have an app release in the playstore and whenever I am working on updates, my testcycles take way too long.
The problem is, if I want to copy my own built apk to my phone, it recognizes it as may apk from the playstore and asks if I want to update it. If I try to update, it stops and says it could not be installed.
So what I have to do is upload my app to google dev console als intern test track and wait until it is there as an update on my phone. This can take nearly an hour. So if I want to test simple stuff, I have to wait nearly an hour to see the results. That is not practicable.

Is there any way to fasten my testing workflow up?
I think I am missing a really simple thing right now.

Currently I am working with some google play game services. Maybe that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found a solution. Not the best, but it is a solution.
I have to delete the app from my phone and then i can install it via ADB or just send the APK via email and install it. That helps to speed things up.
And Bobby Prabowo posted a link to deploygate.com
I will check this out. Maybe that is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can create an "RC" version, as long as it maintain the same app package and send the url to download it via email to the testers

Comment: Yeah i thought so. But if i do this, the phone recognizes the app as installed, asks if i would update it and then crashes on install. If i install it via ADB it says that the signature is wrong. I think because google signs apps too, right?

Comment: hmm, have you try to use this service https://deploygate.com/, my company use it, it helps a lot

Comment: That looks great. I will check this. Thanks.